# Adding on to a username in the URL with mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a site set up right now where each user has their own page.

```
Example: www.example.com/user
```

But now I am wondering how to have different sections for each user.

```
Example: www.example.com/user/photos
```

How can I do this?

Here is my htaccess for the user's page;

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 

RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ userpage.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: If i understand your rewrite rule, you send everything in the url to $1 so if a visitor go to www.exemple.com/user/photos then $1 = user/photos ... you could use a list/explode function to find which page the user want to access. I hope i'm clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the page to which requests are rewritten to is a master controller/dispatcher. The method I use is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then

```
$route = explode('/', $_GET['rt']);
```

Which in your case would yield:

```
array( 'user' , 'photos' )
```

In this way you can use a single script to determine which bit of your program you'd like to load, and then simply include it. If you decide that you want to add different functionality to you site later than you don't have to completely rearrange your code, just add another section to your controller.

Comment: Thank you very much! So as to getting the username in the photos.php I could just explode the URL again I suppose. Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @user2127833 There's a number of different ways you could do it, you could directly access `$_GET['rt']` in photos.php, or put the username [or other vars] into certain variables that are then used in photos.php, maybe pop the username into `$_SESSION`. Most of my projects are OOP-based and the code might look something like `include('class.photos.php'); $obj = new Photos($username); $obj->render();`. It all depends on what works best for you.

Comment: Oh one more thing, I am a little lost on what to do now. So i made an index page and did this `if (count($route)==1){
 header('Location: ');
}` But what do I put in the location to get to `www.example.com./user`? The username equals $route[0]...

Comment: @user2127833 don't do that, you'll end up with an endless redirect loop. Use `include()`.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your Question You  want have a different url for each user like

```
  www.example.com/user1/photos
  www.example.com/user2/photos
```

for that you can use something like this

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ 
 RewriteRule ^ userpage.php?user=%1&url=%2 [S=1,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ userpage.php?user=%1 [S=1,L]
```